# AttributeError in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Very simply, I cannot get .format to work in my code. For Example, when I write:

```
print("abc{0}def".format("x"))
```

I end up with the following error:

```
print("abc{0}def".format("x"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

I am just beginning to learn Python and I am getting this error in PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3

It is interfering with my assignments and my professor has no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Can't repro, that code works fine for me in pycharm 5.0.3 (with python 2.7.8) as well as directly in python (2.7.8 and 3.4.1). What do you see if you run that directly in python (from the shell)?

Comment: Is it using an older version of python by some coincidence, maybe due to some path being set up. try `import sys; print(sys.version_info)`, what do you see? If you cannot resolve it in time you could resort to the older syntax of `print("abc%sdef" % 'x')`.

Comment: Well, as it turns out I went to the Python Interpreter and my issue is the code would not work with version 2, but ran flawlessly with version 3. Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

By switching my *Python Interpreter* in *settings* I was able to switch PyCharm from version 2 to version 3, which solved all of the issues.